# Android JNI GetStaticFieldID fails

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, static-members

I have a MainActivity defined as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  public static ContextActivity   g_ContextActivity;
```

Within my JNI OnLoad() I successfully get a reference to my MainActivity class but I cannot get a reference to the g_ContextActivity static member. I get the error:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no static field with name='g_ContextActivity' signature='com/example/gt/ContextActivity' in class Lcom/example/gt/MainActivity;

```
  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *javaVm, void *reserved)
  {
    g_JavaVM = javaVm;

    JNIEnv *pEnv = NULL;

    if( g_JavaVM->GetEnv( (void **)&pEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK )
    {
      return -1;
    }

    jclass clsMainActivity = pEnv->FindClass( "com/example/gt/MainActivity" );

    LogDebugf( "PDS> (ONLOAD) clsMainActivity: %08lx\n", (long) clsMainActivity );

    if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
      return -1;

    if( g_MainActivityClass )
      pEnv->DeleteGlobalRef( g_MainActivityClass );

    g_MainActivityClass = (jclass) pEnv->NewGlobalRef( clsMainActivity );

    jfieldID fidContextActivity = pEnv->GetStaticFieldID( g_MainActivityClass, "g_ContextActivity", "com/example/gt/ContextActivity" );

    if( JNIException( pEnv ) )
      return -1;

    LogDebugf( "PDS> (ONLOAD) g_ContextActivity ID: %08lx\n", (long) fidContextActivity );
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: If I add a "static int" to MainActivity then I can find it no problem. So the problem would appear to be with the signature??

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer using javap.

javap can be used on the resulting class as follows:

```
javap -s -p MainActivity
```

This produces a list of signatures for the output .class files (not .java source file!). I found the signature:

```
Lcom/example/gt/ContextActivity;
```

..and its now working fine. :-)